# I've used setDefaultFilter but the text is still too pixelated

Tags: text, lua, love2d

```
    Class = require 'class'
push = require 'push'

WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 432
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 243


function love.load()

    love.window.setTitle('Maze')


    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

    smallFont = love.graphics.newFont('HARRYP__.TTF', 25)
    
    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        fullscreen = false,
        vsync = true,
        resizable = false,
    })
end


function love.draw()
    push:apply('start')

    love.graphics.clear(30 / 255, 30 / 255, 50 / 255, 1)

    love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
    love.graphics.printf('Hello, world!', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 6, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')

    push:apply('end')
end
```

I've tried to change the font size but it still comes out pixelated. But I've seen others use a similar code to this and the text comes out all crisp and clear.

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on how detailed your font is.  You're using one that would look better if it weren't inflated after being rendered.  You'll see better results by turning off the virtual playfield at that point, then drawing directly onto the screen.  This is easier to do with titles, where it's easier to position in a general area, rather than a specific location.

```
function love.draw()
    push:apply('start')  --  enable virtual size
    love.graphics.clear(30 /255, 30 /255, 50 /255, 1)

    --  draw your game graphics here

    push:apply('end')  --  disable virtual size

    love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
    love.graphics.printf('Hello, world!', 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT /2 -6, WINDOW_WIDTH, 'center')
end
```

You might also try different fontsizes, and see if that has any effect.

```
smallFont = love.graphics.newFont('HARRYP__.TTF', 30)
```